# Gensim Word2Vec model getting worse by increasing the number of epochs

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm building a Word2Vec model for a category-recommendation on a dataset consisting of ~35.000 sentences for a total of ~500.000 words but only ~3.000 distinct ones.
I build the model basically like this :

```py
def train_w2v_model(df, epochs):
    w2v_model = Word2Vec(min_count=5,
                                 window=100,
                                 size=230,
                                 sample=0,
                                 workers=cores-1,
                                 batch_words=100)
    vocab = df['sentences'].apply(list)
    w2v_model.build_vocab(vocab)
    w2v_model.train(vocab, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, total_words=w2v_model.corpus_total_words, epochs=epochs, compute_loss=True)
    return w2v_model.get_latest_training_loss()
```

I tried to find the right number of epochs for such a model like this :

```py
print(train_w2v_model(1))
=>> 86898.2109375
print(train_w2v_model(100))
=>> 5025273.0
```

I find the results very counterintuitive.
I do not understand how increasing the number of epochs could lead to lower the performance.
It seems not to be a misunderstanding from the function `get_latest_training_loss` since I observe the results with the function `most_similar` way better with only 1 epoch :

100 epochs :

```py
w2v_model.wv.most_similar(['machine_learning'])
=>> [('salesforce', 0.3464601933956146),
 ('marketing_relationnel', 0.3125850558280945),
 ('batiment', 0.30903393030166626),
 ('go', 0.29414454102516174),
 ('simulation', 0.2930642068386078),
 ('data_management', 0.28968319296836853),
 ('scraping', 0.28260597586631775),
 ('virtualisation', 0.27560457587242126),
 ('dataviz', 0.26913416385650635),
 ('pandas', 0.2685554623603821)]
```

1 epoch :

```
w2v_model.wv.most_similar(['machine_learning'])
=>> [('data_science', 0.9953729510307312),
 ('data_mining', 0.9930223822593689),
 ('big_data', 0.9894922375679016),
 ('spark', 0.9881765842437744),
 ('nlp', 0.9879133701324463),
 ('hadoop', 0.9834049344062805),
 ('deep_learning', 0.9831978678703308),
 ('r', 0.9827396273612976),
 ('data_visualisation', 0.9805369973182678),
 ('nltk', 0.9800992012023926)]
```

Any insight on why it behaves like this ? I would have think that increasing the number of epochs would have for sure a positive effect on the **training** loss.

Answer (score 9):

First, the reporting of running training loss is, at least through gensim-3.8.1 (September 2019), a bit of a half-baked feature. It's just a running sum of all loss across all epochs - and thus always increasing – rather than a per-epoch loss that could decrease. There's a long-pending [fix that still needs a little work](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2135), but until that's added, reported numbers need extra comparison to earlier-numbers to detect any epoch-to-epoch decrease.

But also note: even the per-epoch loss isn't a direct measure of model quality/performance for outside purposes. It's only an indicator whether training is still helping on its internal optimization task.

Second, if in fact the model is getting worse at an external evaluation – like whether the `most_similar()` results match human estimations – with more training, then that's often an indication the overfitting is occurring. That is, the (possibly oversized) model is memorizing features of the (likely undersized) training data, and thus getting better at its internal optimization goals in ways that no longer generalize to the larger world of interest.

500K total words is fairly small for a word2vec training set, but could be serviceable if you're also intending to only train a smallish-vocabulary (so there are still many varied examples of each word), and using smallish-dimensioned vectors.

It's not clear what your calculated `min_count` is, but note that increasing it, by shrinking the model, can fight overfitting. But also note that any words appearing fewer times than that threshold will be completely ignored during training, making your effective training data size smaller.

Similarly, it's not clear what `embedding_size` you're using, but trying to make "very large" vectors for a small vocabulary is very overfitting-prone, as there's plenty of "room" for vectors to memorize training details. Smaller vectors force a sort of "compression" on the model that results in learning that's more likely to generalize. (My very-rough rule-of-thumb, not at all really rigorously established, is to never use an dense embedding size larger than the square-root of the expected vocabulary size. So, with 10K tokens, no more than 100-dimension vectors.)

Other observations, probably unrelated to your problem, but perhaps of interest to your goals:

- `window=100` is atypical, and seems far larger than your average text size (~14 words) – if the intent is that all tokens should affect all others, without regard to distance (perhaps because the source data is inherently unordered), that's appropriate, and you might as well go far larger (say 1 million). On the other hand, if a token's direct neighbors are more relevant than others in the same text, a smaller window would make sense.
- there's no good reason to use `batch_words=100` – it will only slow training, and if in fact you have any texts that are larger than 100 words, it will artificially break them up (thus undoing any benefit from the giant `window` value above). (Leave this as the default.)
- the `train()` method will only use `total_examples`, or `total_words`, but not both – so you only need to specify one
- as it appears you might be working with something more like category-recommendation than pure natural language, you may also want to tinker with non-default values of the `ns_exponent` parameter – check the doc-comment & referenced paper in the [class docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec) about that parameter for more details.

Comment: You are right on all your guesses.
All my tokens are by nature unordered, but if I have no list of tokens larger than 100, 100 or 1000000 is the same right ?
Also I am working on a category-recommendation. I will add all the necessary details (regarding number of words in vocabulary, embedding_size and the type of recommendation I tend to perform) in my original post. Thanks !

Comment: Regarding `window`, deep in the training loop, the *effective* window used for any one target-word is in fact a random number that's *up to* the configured number. (This turns out to be a computation-efficient way to overweight nearer neighbors.) Thus a value of `window` close to actual text sizes will more-often use effective windows smaller than the full text, while a generously oversized `window` will only very rarely do so. So for intent of "full text window", generously overlarge values work best.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. I suspect 230-dimensions is too many for a unique vocabulary of only 3k words. Also, with the unordered data and large windows, you essentially only have 35K unique contexts – each complete text. (With a more-typical word2vec setup of ordered natural language and small windows, a 500k-word corpus would have nearly 500k unique contexts, one for each word-occurrence.) Your `most_similar()` results will likely improve (and behave more as expected with regard to more epochs) with a smaller `size`, perhaps somewhere in the 40 to 64 range.

Comment: On the window size parameter see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272370/word2vec-effect-of-window-size-used